# Can nsiTimer cause overflow or memory issues upon repeated use?

Tags: javascript, firefox, timer

In the [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsITimer#initWithCallback%28%29) it says:

> initWithCallback(): Initialize a timer to fire after the given millisecond interval. This version takes a function to call and a closure to pass to that function.

In the this code example:

```
setupTimer: function() {
    var waitPeriod = getNewWaitPeriod();

    myTimer.initWithCallback({ 
        notify: function(t) {
            foo();
            setupTimer();
        }
    },
    waitPeriod,
    Components.interfaces.nsITimer.TYPE_ONE_SHOT);
}
```

How much is actually included in the closure that's passed to the function. Does the closure keep a copy of the entire stack? Is this code sample at risk of stack overflowing or forever increasing memory usage?

Comment: Is there a misplaced `}` in there somewhere? I think the last `}` should be inside the last `)`, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

In theory the closure keeps everything that's in scope for the closure (so in this case the local variables in setupTimer plus whatever variables setupTimer itself closes over).  Note that this is different from the callstack: closure scope in JS is lexical, not dynamic, so it doesn't matter how you reached your function, only what the source of the function looks like.

In practice JS engines optimize closures heavily to speed up access to barewords in closures, so the set of things the closure actually keeps alive might be smaller than the theoretical set I describe above.  But I wouldn't depend on that.